# SharePoint List to CSV Report Creation in below manner

Tags: csv, sharepoint

Any leads in Converting SharePoint List to CSV Report Creation in below shown manner

[image]

Comment: SO is not a free code delivery website. What have you tried you need to show and explain? please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more help

Answer (score 0):

We can use the PowerShell below to achieve it.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://sp2013/sites/team"

#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["TestExportToCSV"]

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()

#Get All List items
$listItems=$list.Items
foreach($item in $listItems) {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $item["Title"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "City" -value $item["City1"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "State" -value $item["State1"]
    $ExportItem1 = New-Object PSObject 
    $ExportItem1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $item["Title"]
    $ExportItem1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "City" -value $item["City2"]
    $ExportItem1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "State" -value $item["State2"]

    #Add the object with property to an Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem1
}
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "c:\ListData.csv" -NoTypeInformation                       

#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
```

[image]